# How to use the dictionary function?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the dictionary

```
d = {'a':3, 'b':7, 'c':8}
```

I was wondering how could i reverse the order of the dictionary in order to make it look like this:

```
d = {3:'a', 7:'b', 8:'c'}
```

I would like to do this without just writing it like this.
Is there a way i can use the first dict in order to obtain the new result?

Comment: It is not sorting. Just reversing keys and values. at first I, too, misunderstood

Comment: _dict_ should not be used as a variable

Comment: Don't use `dict` as a variable name, python builtin dictionary class is already called `dict`

Comment: i changed it, as you can see below the builtin `dict` has been used, this is the type of interference we are trying to avoid

Comment: in python 3.6+ it will work out of the box

Answer (score 12):

Yes. You can call `items` on the dictionary to get a list of pairs of (key, value). Then you can reverse the tuples and pass the new list into `dict`:

```
transposed = dict((value, key) for (key, value) in my_dict.items())
```

Python 2.7 and 3.x also have dictionary comprehensions, which make it nicer:

```
transposed = {value: key for (key, value) in my_dict.items()}
```

Comment: dict comps exist in 2.7+, not just 3.x

Answer (score 2):

```
transposed = dict(zip(d.values(), d))
```